# Convert RGBA to RBG with OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, rgba

I have difficulties with converting RGBA PNG to RGB. I'm using OpenCV C++ to load RGBA PNG with IMREAD_UNCHANGED option and then I'd like to replace the alpha layer with white background.

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: `cv::cvtColor`?

Comment: "replace the alpha layer with white background": that is meaningless. The alpha layer defines transparency, not a color.

Comment: you don't need programming, you need to use the "imagemagick" command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cv::cvtColor` to change the pixel format:

```
cv::Mat rgba = cv::imread("some_path", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
cv::Mat rgb;
cv::cvtColor(rgba, rgb, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```

`rgb` will be a 3 channel rgb image without the alpha channel.

Note that there are 2 ways to order the 3 r,g,b channels: either RGB or BGR. The default in opencv is BGR, but it supports both. Just specify the proper conversion code from `enum ColorConversionCodes`: [Color Conversion Codes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html).

See the complete documentation: [cv::cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab)

**Update:**

After reading the comments by @ChristophRackwitz I realized the OP probably wants to do some kind of blending between the rgb channels and a white background, depending on the alpha channel. I.e. the closest the alpha value for the pixel to 0, the higher the factor of the background in the blend.

This is what the code below does:

```
cv::Mat rgba = cv::imread("image_path", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

cv::Mat rgb_result(rgba.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int y = 0; y < rgba.rows; ++y)
{
    auto const * rgba_pLine = rgba.ptr<cv::Vec4b>(y);
    auto * rbg_result_pLine = rgb_result.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < rgba.cols; ++x)
    {
        auto const & rgba_pixel = rgba_pLine[x];
        auto & rgb_result_pixel = rbg_result_pLine[x];
        float alpha0to1 = rgba_pixel[3] / 255.f;
        rgb_result_pixel[0] = static_cast<uchar>(alpha0to1 * rgba_pixel[0] + (1 - alpha0to1) * 255);
        rgb_result_pixel[1] = static_cast<uchar>(alpha0to1 * rgba_pixel[1] + (1 - alpha0to1) * 255);
        rgb_result_pixel[2] = static_cast<uchar>(alpha0to1 * rgba_pixel[2] + (1 - alpha0to1) * 255);
    }
}
```

The code uses the `ptr` method of `cv::Mat` to access the internal data buffer, and update it efficiently. `rgb_result` will contain the blended rgb image.

Comment: that merely drops the channel, revealing the image data that was previously declared "transparent". it does not compose the picture onto a white background.

Comment: I also had a version that uses only opencv high level functions like `cv::multiply` and `cv::add` but the version above using `ptr` is more efficient.